# Get just one message from rabbitmq queue and unsubscribe

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, bunny

I am using RabbitMq for communication, and I would like to consume just one message and unsubscribe. How to do it in ruby bunny? My subscribe block is pretty easy:

```
  queue.subscribe(block: true) do |delivery_info, properties, payload|
    puts "[consumer] #{q.name} received a message: #{payload}"
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably already figured it out by now, but for anyone else...

According to the [documentation](http://reference.rubybunny.info/Bunny/Channel.html), you can just use basic_get. For example,

```
conn = Bunny.new
conn.start
ch = conn.create_channel
delivery_info, properties, message = ch.basic_get("your_queue_name", :ack => true)
ch.acknowledge(delivery_info.delivery_tag)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be using **#pop** method of queue.

```
conn = Bunny.new
conn.start

ch   = conn.create_channel
q = ch.queue("queue_name")
delivery_info, properties, payload = q.pop
```

[You can find more details about it here](http://reference.rubybunny.info/Bunny/Queue.html#pop-instance_method)